# ORACLE_SELECT_SUM_GROUP_COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I NEED HELP
I WANT TO FIND SUM OF COUNT AND GROUP IT.. I DID SEVERAL SELECTS BUT THE ANSWER IS SAME.

```
SELECT  statusi2, EXTRACT(year FROM reg_date),
       sum(CASE statusi2  
             WHEN 'აქტიური' THEN              
             1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS AQTIURI,
       sum(CASE statusi2
             WHEN 'აქტიური' THEN 0
             ELSE 1
           END) AS  GAUKMEBULI
  FROM gadamxdelta_registracia t group by statusi2,EXTRACT(year FROM reg_date);
```

BOTH CODES ARE SAME

```
SELECT count(EXTRACT(year FROM reg_date)) , statusi2, EXTRACT(year FROM reg_date)  FROM gadamxdelta_registracia

group by statusi2,EXTRACT(year FROM reg_date) ;
```

BUT I WANT TO HAVE

SMTH LIKE THIS

FOR EXAMPLE IN 2010 YEAR 5 PEOPLE ARE REGISTERED IN 2011 3 AND IN 2012 7.
I WANT TO GET THE RESULT:

```
YEAR 2010 - 5,
YEAR 2011 - SUM(5+3) = 8 ,
YEAR 2012 - SUM (8+7)= 15 ,
GROUP BY YEARS AND STATUS..
```

THANK..

Comment: That is a lot of ALL CAPS LETTERS in your post... please fix that **NOW** by hitting [edit]...

Comment: For which DBMS you need the query? Correct your tags please.

Comment: Also consider to take the [tour] and revisit [ask] to get an idea about the feature of the site and what we and you can expect from posts here.

Comment: sorry i'm very new here and also in sql : ))

Comment: What you're looking for is called a running total

Comment: being new doesn't relief you from following our guidance which you didn't follow as far as I can tell. I'm not telling you because I'm rude or impolite, I'm telling you because your posts gets down votes because of the current state your post is in. With enough down votes you won't be able to post new questions in the future and if you're new to a technology you'll probably have more questions later on that you want to ask. So if you're planning to use Stack Overflow as your support site please take our advice seriously.

Answer (score 0):

You want a cumulative sum.  You can do this with an aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT statusi2, yr,
       sum(flag_AQTIURI) AS AQTIURI,
       sum(flag_GAUKMEBULI) AS GAUKMEBULI,
       sum(sum(flag_AQTIURI)) OVER (ORDER BY yr) as running_AQTIURI
FROM (SELECT t.*, EXTRACT(year FROM reg_date) as yr
             (CASE statusi2 WHEN 'აქტიური' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as flag_AQTIURI,
             (CASE statusi2 WHEN 'აქტიური' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as flag_GAUKMEBULI
      FROM gadamxdelta_registracia t
     ) t
GROUP BY statusi2, yr;
```